# How do I switch to some chrome browser tab with pending changes?

Tags: google-chrome

For the "pending changes" I mean those tabs with "leaving site: your changes may not be saved." warnings on closing them....

So, the question is: before the end of my working day, I want to check if I have pending changes in the tabs...  I don't want to dig it one by one, since I might have 100+ tabs...

Note that I don't want to really close my tabs:  I need to use them tomorrow.

Comment: I think that closing Chrome is the only way to find these tabs. You could perhaps save your tabs before closing with an extension such as [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko).

Comment: I found chrome://restart could be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a more specific solution that just highlights these tabs, but here's a workaround for you (and using a tab suspender is good with lots of tabs anyways):

1. Install a known extension that suspends tabs, like [Marvelous Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-marvellous-suspender/noogafoofpebimajpfpamcfhoaifemoa).
2. Configure it to not suspend tabs with active forms, e.g. `Never suspend tabs that contain unsaved form inputs` option in Marvelous Suspender settings.
3. Either set a low auto-suspend time or right click on any web page and select `The Marvelous Suspender` -> `Suspend all other tabs in this window`

Now all tabs without a form should have their favicons dimmed and all with a form will still have regular ones.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It's worth a try. BTW, AFAIK, Chrome recently has some update aiming to reduce the memory usage.  One of the improvement is to suspend inactive tabs. (built-in suspender)

Answer (score 0):

I think that closing Chrome is the only way to find these tabs.

You could perhaps save your tabs before closing with an extension such as [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko).

You also commented that `chrome://restart` is an alternative, which it is,
although it would require you to handle all the tab requests, because
cancelling the restart for one tab's close will leave you without
the other tabs that were already closed.